# Tkinter: "Bad label anchor specification"

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I've been working with the same Python/Tkinter code for a week now, and seemingly out of nowhere I am getting the error "Bad label specification":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/shapirju/Desktop/NumericalAnalysis-Project2/gui.py", line 1188, in <module>
        gui = App()
    File "C:/Users/shapirju/Desktop/NumericalAnalysis-Project2/gui.py", line 62, in __init__
self.createWidgets()
    File "C:/Users/shapirju/Desktop/NumericalAnalysis-Project2/gui.py", line 70, in createWidgets
self.interpLabelframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text = "Interpolation", labelanchor=N)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 776, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::labelframe", kw)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 555, in __init__
Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2096, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: Bad label anchor specification 443664640LN
```

It is caused by the line `self.interpLabelframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text = "Interpolation", labelanchor=N)`

As this worked a few hours ago, maybe this is an environmental issue? I cannot find anything about this issue on Google.

Comment: What do you see when you do `print(N)` right before the line of code that throws an error? My guess is that you've created (or imported) a variable named `N` that has a different value than the tkinter constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to `self.interpLabelframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text = "Interpolation", labelanchor='n')` fixes the issue.

According to the [source code](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/blender-2.78c-windows32.zip/blender-2.78c-windows32/2.78/python/lib/tkinter/test/test_ttk/test_widgets.py) for `LabelFrame`, the label anchors are defined as strings `'n'`, `'we'`, etc.

Comment: But isn't `N` defined as `"n"` in `tkinter.constants`?

Comment: Yes, but it's common to use capital letters in place of the strings. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't I suppose.

Comment: I see. they should fix it to be compatible.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Some systems may not support enum types in parameters". `N` in this case is not an "enum type". It is simply a variable defined by tkinter to contain the letter "n". There is no difference between platforms.